# How to compact mbtiles with mbutil

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles

I'm creating maptiles with arc2earth and ArcGIS and it creates a lot of duplicate tiles.
I would like to reduce its size using mbtiles. I think it is possible to "compact" tiles, but I don't find the way. 
Do you know if mbtiles still have compact command or it is just been deprecated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment `mbutil` doesn't expose this as an option - TileMill is the only client that supports properly compressed tiles. Of course, `mbutil` is an [open source project](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil), so if you're game, you can built it and add it.